# Target debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets failed: Exception: Failed to codesign with identity -

Tags: flutter, dart

I have problem when I do build ios since about one month only with ios
I can't find fix for this problem from search internet

I did change signature and certificate and delete project and re-create without fix

this is problem in xcode

```
error: Target debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets failed: Exception: Failed to codesign /Users/mohammedalghurairi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fpfnxymfuwkswxabxobwfhbmujgy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.framework/App with identity -.
/Users/mohammedalghurairi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fpfnxymfuwkswxabxobwfhbmujgy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.framework/App: replacing existing signature
/Users/mohammedalghurairi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fpfnxymfuwkswxabxobwfhbmujgy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.framework/App: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
Failed to package /Users/mohammedalghurairi/code2/khlea2.
```

and pubspec.yaml code

```
name: khlea2
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 0.1.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.1 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  align_positioned: ^3.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.15
  url_launcher: ^6.1.10
  matrix4_transform: ^2.0.1
  firebase_core: ^2.12.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.6.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.7.1
  sqflite: ^2.2.8
  google_mobile_ads: ^3.0.0
  assets_audio_player: ^3.0.6
  path: any
  intl: ^0.18.1
    

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1
  
flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/icon.png"
  

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/audios/
    - assets/data/
```

Comment: did you solved this error? I'm getting same issue but stucked

Answer (score 0):

Go to Targets > Built Phases > Run Script:

```html
xattr -cr ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData || echo Clear
```